# My code doesnt work in firefox...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeater, repeat

I have this code that seems to work in chrome and safari ( not sure about opera and ie.. just havent tested.. ) but in firefox it *at least* doesnt repeat the play function but just runs it once.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZL5XN/

HTML:

```
<div class="Start">Play</div><div class="Stop">Stop</div>
<br /><br />
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet...</p>
```

JS:

```
var myTimeOut, Stop, stop_flag;

$('.Start').click( function () {
    stop_flag = 0;
    Repeat();
});

$('.Stop').click( function () {
    clearTimeout(Stop);
    stop_flag = 1;
    $('p').show('slow');
});



function Repeat() {
    if(stop_flag == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $('p').show('slow').delay(400).hide('slow', function() {Stop = setTimeout(Repeat(), 1100)});
    }
}
```

Question is.. any ideas why it is not working in firefox

Comment: Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)

Comment: @Max Error: EDONTUSEEVAL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be saying:

```
Stop = setTimeout(Repeat, 1100);
```

Note the missing brackets.  At the moment you're telling it to call the function *returned* by `Repeat()`, which of course there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why firefox is the only one conmplaining but you've written your setTimeout wrong. It should be:

```
$('p').show('slow').delay(400).hide('slow', function() {Stop = setTimeout(Repeat, 1100)});
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is this

Change:

> setTimeout(Repeat(), 1100)

To:

> setTimeout("Repeat()", 1100) or setTimeout(Repeat, 1100)

See the working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZL5XN/1/

Comment: **don't** use the version enclosed in quotes!